# How do I convert datetime format Year-Quarter to Quarter-Year in python?

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

Now I have a column like this in a pandas dataframe:

```
Year_Quarter
2014Q1
2015Q1
2015Q2
2016Q3
```

I got this column by converting another column of date using the following code:

```
combine['Publish Date'] = pd.to_datetime(combine['Publish Date']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
combine['Year_Quarter'] = pd.to_datetime(combine['Publish Date']).dt.to_period('Q').astype(str)
```

How do I convert this date format into:

```
Q12014
Q12015
Q22015
Q32016
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Use string slicing and concatenation. `s[-2:] + s[:4]`

Comment: similar to what @Barmar suggests, only remember to use the `.str` accessor for a series: `df1['Year_Quarter'].str[-2:].add(df1['Year_Quarter'].str[:4])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this with [`strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.PeriodIndex.strftime.html) to get the custom format:

```
combine['Year_Quarter'] = pd.to_datetime(combine['Publish Date']).dt.to_period("Q").dt.strftime('Q%q%Y')
```

---

Or as is suggested in the comments by @Barmar and @anky, you could slice the column too:

```
combine['Year_Quarter'] = pd.to_datetime(combine['Publish Date']).dt.to_period('Q').astype(str) 
combine['Year_Quarter']=combine['Year_Quarter'].str[-2:].add(combine['Year_Quarter'].str[:4])
```

---

Both outputs:

```
combine['Year_Quarter']

Q12014
Q12015
Q22015
Q32016
```

Comment: Solve my problem! Thank you very much!